# Comic book about a space adventurer, with retro guns and suit

Tags: story-identification, comics, space

4-6 years ago I read several comics books about a space adventurer (I don't remember what he was really doing, I think it was in exile) with retro-looking suit and guns (50s style). He has a square jaw, black short hair and always smokes a cigar.

The only elements specifics elements I remember are spoilers, in the arc about the past of the hero :

> When we learn the past of the hero, we see that he was a farmer when two aliens race (green blobs on one side versus robots on the other) choose to use the earth as a battlefield, exterminating the human race in the meantime.

This arc end with :

> To avenge the human race, he send a bomb on the homeworld of one of the alien races (the green blobs).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds a lot like **[Fear Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_Agent)**:

[image]

Particularly the story arc entitled *[The Last Goodbye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_Agent#Issues_12-15:_.22The_Last_Goodbye.22)*:

> Enraged at the loss of his comrades, Heath takes a bomb to the Dressite homeworld, despite his close friend Otto's dying wish that not Heath (sic) commit genocide of the entire Dressite race.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That would be cowboy bebop, sounds like. One of the best anime in my opinion. He was a bounty hunter and had a sweet ship, a crew of oddballs.

Comment: How do you figure? There were no intelligent aliens in Cowboy Bebop, definitely no arc with blowing up an alien planet. And the question was about a comic book, not an anime.

Comment: Oh well, just trying to help. Black hair, square jaw, smoking. So it's not cowboy bebop then.

Comment: :) Honestly, if you edit your answer with the parts that *do* match such as the square jaw and the smoking, that might make your answer decent., especially if you also indicate the parts that don't fit. We don't mind partial matches here.